F2 key to rename not working on Windows 11
EDIT: I have fixed the issue. Apparently, something was altered within the keyboard by the previous owner using the Razer software. I installed the software anyway and let it detect the keyboard. From now on, the F2 behaviour was fixed, so I uninstalled the software after which it kept working.
I have a Razer BlackWidow 2019 keyboard on a Windows 11 machine WITHOUT Razer Synapse. This keyboard comes with F1-F12 keys mapped to some media functionality (volume up/down, pause, next, etc.) These functions are meant to be used in combination with the fn key.
However, F2, which I use quite often to rename files triggers Volume Down without pressing fn with it!
I tried disabling media keys globally in Services (found in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617282/how-to-disable-special-keyboard-keys). This stops Windows from lowering the volume when pressing F2.
But here's the thing: F2 still does not work to rename a file! F2 is doing nothing at all now!
If anyone has a suggestion, please let me know.

You could try recording a macro to change the media key to a function key. See page 9 of the manual. You might have to undo the change you mentioned in the question first.

@John, do you have exactly the same setup as I do? On a normal keyboard the F2 key is working fine.

@AndrewMorton For macros, do I need Razer's software?

@Radiofreak1041 it looks like the on-the-fly macro recording facility might be built into the keyboard.

@Radiofreak1041 I guess the default suggestion for keyboard remapping is to try AutoHotKey. Also, there is scant chance it'll work for a Razer keyboard, but Dell laptops use Fn+Esc to swap between using the function keys as function keys or as other functions.

There is going to be a key combination to toggle this on and off. It is different for every keyboard, but common options are fn+space, shift+fn, fn+esc, pressing fn twice quickly, etc.
This will be mentioned in the manual that came with your keyboard. Also, this keyboard has status lights. If any of them are red, for example the 4th and 5th, try turning them off using fn+F9 and fn+10 and see if that fixes it.
I was unable to find a manual online to troubleshoot it though.

I included a link to the manual in my comment on the question. Unless there is a more in-depth manual or I missed something, it doesn't mention toggling the "feature".
